# Error al intentar consumir un servicio web: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, webservice, axis

Estoy intentando consumir un web service de una empresa en particular. Ya obtuve el wsdl y me generó los códigos java correspondiente. Ahora, cuando intento probar un servicio, me sale el siguiente error :

```
[ERROR] 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at fxglobal.services.ces.PingDocument$Factory.parse(PingDocument.java:140)
    at org.tempuri.FXGlobalSendingMessageReceiverInOut.fromOM(FXGlobalSendingMessageReceiverInOut.java:1269)
    at org.tempuri.FXGlobalSendingMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(FXGlobalSendingMessageReceiverInOut.java:80)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:106)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sA21292DCBE528E61DDC23251202D2812.TypeSystemHolder. Make sure the generated binary files are on the classpath.
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:783)
    at fxglobal.services.ces.PingDocument.<clinit>(PingDocument.java:20)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sA21292DCBE528E61DDC23251202D2812.TypeSystemHolder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1339)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:769)
    ... 32 more
```

Estoy utilizando Axis 2. Alguien tiene una idea a que se refiere y como solucionarlo?

Comment: Saludos una pregunta has tenido algún resultado con soapUI?